Почему не работает заполнение View элементов при вызове метода из другого класса?
В моём приложении нужно по нажатию на объект списка активировать активити, поля в котором будут заполнены исходя переданного в него объекта. Активировать экран получается, но вызов функции, которую я использую для заполнения и вызываю прямо за ним ничего не даёт - экран появляется в стандартном варианте. Вот вызовы активити и функции для его заполнения:
            override fun getTrackAndStart(track: Track) {
                val displayIntent = Intent(this@SearchActivity, PlayerActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(displayIntent)
                PlayerActivity().bind(track)
            }
        }

class PlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var titleName: TextView
    private lateinit var artistName: TextView
    private lateinit var playerImg: ImageView
    private lateinit var trackLength: TextView
    private lateinit var trackAlbum: TextView
    private lateinit var trackYear: TextView
    private lateinit var trackStyle: TextView
    private lateinit var trackCountry: TextView
    private lateinit var staticTrackAlbum: TextView

    private val radius: Float by lazy {
        8 * this.resources.displayMetrics.density
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player)

        titleName = findViewById(R.id.player_title_name)
        artistName = findViewById(R.id.player_artist_name)
        playerImg = findViewById(R.id.player_img)

        trackLength = findViewById(R.id.player_length_empty)
        trackAlbum = findViewById(R.id.player_album_empty)
        trackYear = findViewById(R.id.player_year_empty)
        trackStyle = findViewById(R.id.player_style_empty)
        trackCountry = findViewById(R.id.player_country_empty)

        val backButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.player_back)

        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }

    fun bind(track: Track){
        titleName.text = track.trackNameItem
        artistName.text = track.artistNameItem
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(track.trackAvatarItem.replaceAfterLast('/',"512x512bb.jpg"))
            .centerCrop()
            .transform(RoundedCorners(radius.toInt()))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_av)
            .into(playerImg)
        trackLength.text = SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(track.trackTimeItem)
        if(track.collectionName.isEmpty()){
            trackAlbum.visibility = View.GONE
            staticTrackAlbum.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        else{
            trackAlbum.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            staticTrackAlbum.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            trackAlbum.text = track.collectionName
        }
        trackYear.text = track.rYear
        trackStyle.text = track.genre
        trackCountry.text = track.country
    }
}

Какой может быть решение в данной ситуации? Буду благодарен любому предположению.

передавайте параметры через Intent.putExtra

это нужно прописать для каждого параметра при инициализации или передаче значений?

Не нужно вызывать конструктор любой активити. Никогда. Все что хотите ей передать запихивайте в интент, а в onCreate() из него читайте.
